# How to get top 3 values from a vector smaller than a particular value?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector {42.195 42.195 39.025 40.075 34.220 42.195 39.750}. Here I want to get top 3 values just smaller than 42.195. Below is my approach.

1. I sorted the vector in descending order.
2. Initialize an output vector and a counter=0.
3. Then I traversed through the vector and checked if an element is **not equal** to 42.195. If it is so, increment the counter. If counter value is <= 3, push that element in the output vector. Once the counter value becomes greater than 3, break out of the for loop and return the output vector.

The above approach looks logically fine, but the code is not working fine while comparing each element with 42.195 value. Please help me.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int validateData(vector<float> &arr){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
        if(arr[i] <= 0.0){
            cout<<"\nInvalid data";
            return -1; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

vector <float> getTop3(vector<float>& arr){
    if(validateData(arr) == -1)
        cout<<"\nCannot perform operation";
    else {
        vector<float> output;
        int count = 0;
        cout<<"Sorted values are: \n";
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), greater<float>());
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
            if(arr[i] != 42.195) {
                count++;
                if(count <= 3)
                    output.push_back(arr[i]);
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        cout<<"\nOutput vector is\n";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < output.size() ; i++){
            cout<<output[i]<<" ";
        }
        return output;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    vector<float> arr;
    cout<<"Arguments are:\n";
    for(int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++){
        arr.push_back(stof(argv[i]));
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    //Function call
    getTop3(arr);
}
```

Below is the output.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Also, if you are sorting the data, you can use [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) which makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: 'if(arr[i] != 42.195)' this may cause problem due to the float rounding. You can change to 'if ( fabs(arr[i] - 42.195)  > 1.0e-7)' set a tolerance for equality of two float numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) followed by [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) can do the job:

```
std::vector<float> get_top3(std::vector<float> v, float threshold)
{
    auto end = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](auto f){ return f < threshold; });
    if (std::distance(v.begin(), end) <= 3) return {v.begin(), end};
    std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, end, std::greater<>{});
    return {v.begin(), v.begin() + 3};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<float> arr = {42.195, 42.195, 39.025, 40.075, 34.220, 42.195, 39.750};
    
    for (auto f : get_top3(arr, 42.195))
        std::cout <<  f << " ";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d42774d8d8dc76aa)

One of your issue is that: `42.195 != 42.195f`.